# Numbers not showing in generated PDF on some pages after text replace PDFSharp

Tags: .net, pdf, reporting-services, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I'm working on this extremely annoying bug where the number 8 is not showing up in my PDF. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and 0 are fine, only 8 is showing a square on SOME of the pages (the portrait ones).

The application works as follows:

- Generate PDF on SSRS ( some landscape, some portrait )
- Merge PDF using PDFSharp
- Update page numbers using PDFSharp

Now, on the first part of the overall report (portrait pages), the 8 is not showing. In the second part of the report, the 8 IS showing.

I don't see any differences in the RDL (language, fonts, even size of the box). The whole document is in ANSI encoding, and so the code to write the new page numbers is the same for the whole document.

[image: 8 not showing on first couple of pages]

[image: 8 is showing on some of the other pages]

I saw that Aspose had a problem like this (http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/528718/number-8-missing-in-pdf-file-with-some-viewers.aspx), but I'm not using Aspose.

I checked appending (char) 0x38, and it doesn't show up. 0x37 and 0x39 are. String encoding is done for both cases like Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes() or Encoding.Default.

The code for generating the PDFS through SSRS is identical, except for report name of course. I could not find any encoding information in the RDL itself.

Page numbers are replaced, using PDFSharp Stream.Value = 'newvalue'.

All ideas are VERY much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I ran the number replacemenent through Aspose and the 8 showed up, as expected, on all pages. Using simple pdf.Pages.Accept(textFragmentAbsorber);.

**Update II**

So after some playing around, I'm pretty sure it has to do with the way I'm replacing the text in the document, and the encoding of the replaced string.

Extraction is as follows:

```
    public byte[] UpdatePageNumbers(byte[] file, PageNumberingConfigurationBase config)
    {
        var doc = PdfReader.Open(new MemoryStream(file), PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);
        for (int i = 0; i < doc.PageCount; i++)
        {
            var pageNr = i + 1;
            var page = doc.Pages[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < page.Contents.Elements.Count; j++)
            {
                var element = page.Contents.Elements.GetDictionary(j);
                var content = element.AsString();

                if (content.Contains(config.SearchTemplate))
                {
                    var newContent = content.Replace(
                        config.SearchTemplate,
                        config.GetReplacementTextForPage(pageNr, doc.PageCount));

                    element.Stream.Value = newContent.AsByteArray();
                }
            }
        }

        return doc.AsByteArray();
    }
```

With helper class:

```
public static class ElementExtensions
{
    public static string AsString(this PdfDictionary dict)
    {
        return GetString(dict.Stream.Value);
    }

    public static byte[] AsByteArray(this string stream)
    {
        return GetBytes(stream);
    }

    static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        return Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(str);
    }

    static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytes);
    }
}
```

The document encoding inside the PDF is:

```
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
```

Here's how the documents are merged:

```
    public byte[] MergePdf(params byte[][] pdfs)
    {
        var outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

        for (int i = 0; i < pdfs.Count(); i++)
        {
            var document = PdfReader.Open(new MemoryStream(pdfs[i]), PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

            // Create the output document
            foreach (PdfPage pdfPage in document.Pages)
            {
                outputDocument.Pages.Add(pdfPage);
            }
        }

        return outputDocument.AsByteArray();
    }
```

**Sample files**

So here are the sample files:

This is one report, generated 3 times, then merged, then page numbers updated.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxzqw0y2tvu3v9a/before_update.pdf
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ui26l0qsunhcune/after_update.pdf

Please note that now ALL the numbers are shown as boxes/squares..

Comment: What viewer did you use? Only one, or several (including the canonically "correct" free Acrobat Reader)? Can you create a 1-page PDF that exhibits the problem for you and post it on a publicly available location?

Comment: Both Fox and Adobe. Hmm.. that's a little difficult since I'm doing a project for a large bank and I'm affraid they don't want me to post their stuff on the internet. I'll see what I can do though.

Comment: I'd support @Jongware's request of a sample document. Aside from that you seem to be replacing the page number character identifiers originally in the document by your new ones. Is it possible that the font used for them is only partially embedded and simply does not contain the glyph for 8? Probably only in case of the landscape source documents the glyph for 8 is not embedded. If you indeed have to deal with partially embedded fonts, I'd propose completely removing the original page numbers and adding new ones using a font you explicitly add to the merged document.

Comment: I'll work on it. I can tell you that the font is just a simple Verdana 7pt, nothing special. It's the same font as is used on the other pages that do work. They are all replaced in the same loop that runs through the PDFSharp page elements.

Comment: I'm afraid without sample document all we can do is guess. Furthermore the pivotal code sections could help.

Comment: *Extraction is as follows* - So you indeed simply edit a content string without checking whether or not the glyphs for the edited string are contained in the font current when the string is drawn. *The document encoding inside the PDF is: `/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding`* - this does *not* imply that glyphs for all WinAnsi characters are present in the font.

Comment: @mkl, thank you for your continued support. You are right, the thing is that I don't understand why it shows up on one page, and not the other, and we're talking about Verdana and the number 8.
I'm working on an empty RDL now to reproduce this annoying issue, then I can provide you with a sample.

Comment: *the thing is that I don't understand why ...* - most likely different subsets of the font in question are included in the font resources referenced from those different pages.

Comment: Thanks once more - I added the sample files.

Comment: @mkl - So could it be the case that I had the problem because on that particular page, no 8 was used, and therefore, it wasn't available? If so, could we solve this writing '0123456789' somewhere invisible on the page?

Comment: *could we solve this writing '0123456789' somewhere invisible on the page* - Yes, that sounds plausible, obviously using the same font as in the page footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mkl, I found the solution. We're going to add a hidden textbox in the report, with 0123456789 inside. The reason is 'font subsetting' by SSRS.

SSRS will not embed font characters that are not used on the page in order to save space. Therefore, if no '8' was present on the page, the '8' which replaced into the page, was not visible. Therefore, when I created a page with no text on it, I got only squares/boxes.

Thanks again @mkl.

See: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159713(SQL.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159713%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

> When possible, the PDF rendering extension embeds the ***subset*** of each
>   font that is needed to display the report in the PDF file. Fonts that
>   are used in the report must be installed on the report server.